# MySQL constraint for numeration column

Tags: mysql, constraints

I have situation when a I have to store complex data number in the database. Something like that `21/2011` where `21` is document number, but `2011` is document year. So I need some constraint to handle uniqueness because there is document with number `21/2010` and `21/2012`.

How can I create such constraint when numbering starts each from 1 and there is uniqueness check for complex number value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE documents
        (
        year INT NOT NULL,
        no INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY (year, no)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT
INTO    documents(year)
VALUES  (2010),
        (2010),
        (2011);

SELECT  *
FROM    documents;
```

Unfortunately, the `AUTO_INCREMENT` part will only work for `MyISAM` tables, however, uniqueness check will work in `InnoDB` as well, though you will have to provide the numbers explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem, you can simply create an unique key over these both columns.

An other way would be to store "21/2010" as single varchar column.